# Laravel submitting form as GET but coded as POST

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've just created a form with blade and for some reason its posting with GET even though the HTML says POST and to a different URL (see gif http://cl.ly/image/381k1j0t3x3c )

Routes:
http://cl.ly/image/101V1g2l2X1K

Controler:
http://cl.ly/image/1P2b0O0u3U0q

Blade File:
http://cl.ly/image/2m3B0g3g1T1S

Has anyone had this issue before, anyone see something dumb I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, remove `<form role='form'>` tag. Don't wrap `form` with another `form`

```
{{ Form::open(['action'=>'CategoryController@adminStoreCategory']) }}
    ....
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks... I should've seen that haha.. well it is 1:30 am.